# Enable authentication to access the kubernetes dashboard ui

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes on a local Mac OS docker installation.

I've installed the dashboard ui following these [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/):

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
kubectl proxy
```

When I try to access the ui by http://localhost:8001/ui I'll get a prompt to either provide a kubeconfig file or a token.

So I try to configure authentication: The [dashboard docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) refer to the [authentication docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#static-password-file):

> Basic authentication is enabled by passing the
>   `--basic-auth-file=SOMEFILE` option to API server. ...
>
> password,user,uid,"group1,group2,group3"

**Questions:**

- Which command passes the option `--basic-auth-file` to kubernetes?
- How do I have to specify the password file? Which groups are needed by the dashboard?
- Is the authentication stored in the kubeconfig file, so that I can use that file for authentication?

Comment: I use token to connect to the cluster, with `kubectl config view` I get the token. I tried to create an auth-file in the past and it seems very similar to the `kubectl config view` maybe it can help you

Comment: kubectl config view says: "...client-certificate-data: REDACTED..." But when I look into the file ~/.kube/config I can see a key. Unfortunatly this key does not help. But then I've seen, that it is possible to skip the authentification. So after skipping I'll get to the ui.

Comment: Nevertheless I access the dashboard as an anonymous user. So I'm still curious how I can log in ...